# How to check multiple possible combinations of if statements?

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, combinations

So I have 20 conditions and im trying to check different combinations.

**for example:**

1 and 2 or 3
1 or 2 or 3 and 4
4 and 5 or 2
4 and 5 and 2 or 9
ect....

I'm trying to figure out what should I do. I though maybe use a swich case but I'm not really sure how to do that in a case like that with so many options.

I **dont** need to check All the possible options but i would like to try at least 15-20 "and " " or" combinations.

would love some advice here!
:)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all combinations:

```
a = '1234567890'
b = list(a)

for c in b:
    for d in b:
        print(c+d)
```